# Encoding video in Android using cv::Mat and MediaCodec

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, android-mediacodec

I'm using an Android 4.3 device to encode video using cv::Mat.

I took a look to [grafika hacks](https://github.com/google/grafika) and [BigFrake samples](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#samples), I have tested them and they are working.

I have my cv::Mat in c++, and using JNI I can send a buffer o buffer pointer to Java, where I have prepared and Encoder:

```
///////////////////////// Configure encoder
    // QVGA at 2Mbps
    mWidth = 320;
    mHeight = 240;
    mBitRate = 2000000;
    //////////////////////////////////////

    MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
    if (codecInfo == null) 
    {
        // Don't fail CTS if they don't have an AVC codec (not here, anyway).
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unable to find an appropriate codec for " + MIME_TYPE);
    }
    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "found codec: " + codecInfo.getName());

    mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, mWidth, mHeight);

    // Set some properties.  Failing to specify some of these can cause the MediaCodec
    // configure() call to throw an unhelpful exception.

    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, mBitRate);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);
  //  format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
  //  format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 200);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface); // PROBLEM: Color_formatSurface is the only want who works!!!!!
    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "format: " + format);

    // Create a MediaCodec encoder, and configure it with our format. 
    //
    mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    mEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    //mInputSurface = new CodecInputSurface(mEncoder.createInputSurface()); // I don't want to use a surface
    mEncoder.start();
    inputBuffers = mEncoder.getInputBuffers();
    outputBuffers = mEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
```

The problem is, MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT only admit COLOR_FormatSurface or COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar, but my data is in RGB, no surface metadata or YUV. I have tried using the 3 codec I can use:

```
//private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";    // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
//private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/mp4v-es";    // Mp4
private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/3gpp";    // 3gpp
```

1) Is the color format a problem in this case? I mean, Is possible to use directly, I must use a PixelBuffer to fake a COLOR_FormatSurface, or convert my data to YUV?

2) What way is the most efficient to copy data from a cv::Mat.data pointer into MediaCodec buffer?

**Update 1:**

- Before extracting CV:Mat, I have a FBO OpenGL. I think that another solution will be render the FBO in the InputSurface to directly use MediaCodec to encode the video, without share context. But I had not found references to copy an FBO from a OpenGL context to CodecInputSurface.

Comment: The Grafika "Record GL app" demonstrates recording to a Surface by blitting from an FBO (among other approaches).  Unless you need to support API 16/17, you should avoid the ByteBuffer input to MediaCodec, as it requires YUV data and is much slower.  You can upload RGB data to a texture with `glTexImage2D`; there's a benchmark in Grafika (512x512 RGBA) that indicates it's pretty fast on current devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rendering of FBO to codec input surface is pretty sraight forward. You will need to `GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);`
then bind frameBuffer's output texture id to a mediacodec context, i.e. makeCurrent firstly,

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
```

and use regural copy shader similar that exist in mediacodec stufs, but without OES texture but with texture 2D: for example

```
private static final String VERTEXT_SHADER =
        "uniform mat4 uOrientationM;\n" +
            "uniform mat4 uTransformM;\n" +
            "attribute vec2 aPosition;\n" +
            "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
            "vTextureCoord = (uTransformM * ((uOrientationM * gl_Position + 1.0) * 0.5)).xy;" +
            "}";

    private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
            "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
            "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
            "}";
```

Workable sample solution for that copy as well as FBO initialization you may find in Intel INDE samples for Android https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 ways:

1. convert RGB buffer to NV12 (or YV12), configure encoder to accept NV12(YV12) and copy NV12 buffer to encoder's one - i am not sure that it will work on all devices, since color format support is inconsistent on different devices, more info on fadden's page in Q5\A5: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/
2. create a bitmap from RGB buffer, put it to surface\texture created by createInputSurface() by GLUtils.texImage2D() - not sure about performance here